# Joomla dev - Probleme with an editor field in theconfiguration context

Tags: joomla, format, editor, field

I'm currently developing a component that includes an "editor" field in his parameters (the form mandated by the com_config).

The value of the "filter" attribute of the field in the "config.xml" file is : "raw".
Despite all the HTML here is fired, remains only the textual content.

On this website I'm doing the same thing for the parameters of a plugin and It work very well here, so I think that it's not a story of Joomla! configuration or editor configuration (I use the same editor with the same user account) ...

Is it a constraint imposed by the configuration component ??

Thank you for your lights!

Comment: SOME NEW INFOS : I've tried with two editor : TinyMCE and CodeMiror who produce the same result. I really begin to trust that Joomla! don't accept raw content in the configuration data.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say without some code to look at, but the raw filter should not remove HTML.

You could try building the same functionality using http://www.component-creator.com and view the code it generates or simply just use the built component instead of your own code.

Comment: Thankz for your help. ComponentCreator is maybe a great tool but are you sure that I can add this functionality to the generated component ?? Honestly I have no time to lose I'm pretty late on this project and it is for this reason that I would like to be safe before using this tool that I really do not know. Please check the comment that I added to my question.

Comment: I don't use specific code, just this field type : http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type in my configuration file "config.xml". The code that I had in the field is very simple, just HTML code with a paragraph and a picture.

Comment: Try the component creator, it will take 5 minutes to make a component, and yes it support all Joomla's field types.